# Getting hrefs under <li> from <ul> using Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

This might not be the best question ever, but I really can't get this to work.

What I'm trying to do is to get the hrefs from the html below.

```html
<ul id="nav-products">
  <li><a class="" href="/shop/hats/">yellow good looking hat</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="/shop/shoes/">cat feet holders</a></li>
</ul>
```

This, from Node.js using Cheerio.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const html = fs.readFileSync('text.html', "utf8")

const $ = cheerio.load(html);



$('#nav-products').each((i, el) => {
    const category = $(el).text();
    const children = $(el).children();


    console.log(children.attr('href'));
    console.log(category);
});
```

However, I've tried multiple methods and got none to work. Ex:

`const link = $(el).attr('href');`

But the `link`/`children.attr('href')` constant is still undefined.
Thanks.

Comment: you could also `.find(...)` to look up anchors as @Marcus suggested to use their `href`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code snippet, `children` contains the list items of the unordered list, but the `href` attribute is defined on the anchor elements which are in turn children of their list item parents. So, you need to iterate `children` and get each child's the children to get the anchor items.

```
$('#nav-products').each((i, ul) => {
  const children = $(ul).children();
  children.each((i, li) => {
    const children = $(li).children();
    children.each((i, a) => {
      console.log($(a).attr('href'));
      console.log($(a).text())
    })
  })
});
```

EDIT: Here is an example of using `find()` as suggested by @82Tuskers

```
$('#nav-products').each((i, ul) => {
  const children = $(ul).children();
  const selectedAnchors = $(ul).find("A");
  selectedAnchors.each((i, a) => {
    console.log($(a).attr('href'));
    console.log($(a).text())
  })
});
```

My suggestion is to make this a lot easier by using a selector which scope the anchor elements of list items of the `#nav-products` list as follows:

```
$('#nav-products LI A').each((i, el) => {
  console.log($(el).text());
  console.log($(el).attr('href'));
});
```

You can try all snippets on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@mwittig/cheerio)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're iterating the `a`'s:

```
let links = $('a').map((i, a) => {
  return {
    text: $(a).text(),
    href: $(a).attr('href')
  }
}).get()
```

Also in general you want `map` instead of `each` if you're going to do something useful with the data.